# Ubuntu hangs randomly and screen flickering abnormally

Tags: drivers, graphics, 22.04, crash, nvidia-geforce

For the last two months, I have been facing constant issues with Ubuntu 22.04, now it frustrates me and forces me to migrate to another operating system.

My screen is flickering randomly, the machine hangs randomly. I don't know what happened with it.

It happens to me in almost any activity such as I am playing a video in VLC or the default media player or coding in VSCode or opening multiple browsers. In addition to that my mouse is also not smoothly scrolling or moving across multiple screens. I felt a lagging randomly. No system updates are pending.

The current problem really sucks productivity. I have a system that is capable to bear enough load of code and process, but this current issue is the biggest issue for me.

I have posted the same issue in nvidia forum, but it seems forum is idle. Nvidia team is also not responding.

Hope to get an answer from the community.

**Ubuntu software updates settings:**

[image]

**Other software updates settings:**

[image]

**Additional drivers settings**

[image]

**CPU**

[image]
[image]

**Graphics card information**

[image]

**Extended hardware information**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Installed graphics driver:**

[image]

**Screenshots of flickered screen**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: When it first occurred, did you look at what changes had just happened, ie. if it was the switch from 5.15 (GA) kernel to 5.19 (HWE) then an easy *fix* would have been to put yourself on the GA kernel path (ie. remain on 5.15 which is supported for the life of 22.04). Last *two* months is rather vague & somewhat unhelpful, as when the first change is noticed is most useful; as you look at changes/upgrades that occurred during the prior session(s) but particularly last session. Alternatively have you looked for clues in system logs?

Comment: In syslog I have seen some randon crash logs. If it would, then I put system log here also.

Answer (score 1):

You are running the "nouveau" driver on X-Org. Usually you get a better experience when installing the "tested Nvidia driver", which appears in your "Additional driver Settings" page.

Select that entry, install and reboot.

In addition you might go back to kernel 5.15 in case the newer kernel won't work correctly with the NVIDIA driver.

Comment: Thank you for response. Do you mean that I should use nvidia-driver-470 for my Feforce GT 730?

Comment: Certainly. Im using the driver on my GTX 760 - works perfectly

Comment: You are right. From afternoon I have changed the driver, it seems working fine. But now it's starting to freezing the mouse. Right now there are almost 20 tabs has opened in the browser. So I am sure that there is something wrong with drivers or hardware.

Comment: Could you select the 5.15 kernel as guiverc suggested? (Reboot into grub and select it)